# jqGrid 4.8.0 - the 'searchGrid' function is not saving your filter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free jqGrid 4.8.0.

I noticed that the `searchGrid` (what is called 'Advanced Searching') is not saving the filter criteria anymore after I close it.

I compared the same exact code on 4.7.1, and on 4.7.1 it did save the filter.

That led me to think maybe somehow the default option for 'recreateFilter' was set to 'true' in 4.8.0, so I also set `recreateFilter: false`, to be on the safe side.  It didn't help.

Appreciate any advice to workaround the issue.

Here is the code, basically I'm calling it from outside of the grid as a function:

```
function advancedFilterConfig (nameOfGrid,gridName) {
    $(nameOfGrid).jqGrid('searchGrid', {
        multipleSearch:true,
        showQuery: true,
        multipleGroup:true,
        caption: "Advanced Search",
        sFilter: "afilters",
        Find: "Apply",
        Reset: "Reset & Close",
        closeAfterReset: true,
        width:'auto',
        recreateForm: true,
        recreateFilter: false,
        errorcheck: true,
        overlay:false,
        onSearch: function () {
            //Hide the tool bar
            $("#gview_"+gridName).find('.ui-search-toolbar').hide();

            var postData = $(nameOfGrid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
            var advancedFilter = jQuery.parseJSON(postData.afilters);
            delete postData.afilters;

            //Set the advanaced filter here.
            gridsSettingObject[gridName].advancedFilter = advancedFilter;
            gridsSettingObject[gridName].useAdvancedFilter = true;
            changeToggleSwitch(0, '#' + gridName + '-as-on-off-div');
            sessionList($(nameOfGrid),gridName);
        },
        onReset: function () {
            delete gridsSettingObject[gridName].advancedFilter;
            gridsSettingObject[gridName].useAdvancedFilter = false;
            changeToggleSwitch(1, '#' + gridName + '-as-on-off-div');
            //Unhide the tool bar
            $("#gview_"+gridName).find('.ui-search-toolbar').show();
            sessionList($(nameOfGrid),gridName);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Do you mean Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript 4.8/4.8.1/4.8.2 or [Free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)? Could you describe *how you use* `searchGrid`? (by usage of `navGrid` for example). How the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: I added the code. I'm not using it from navGrid.

Comment: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/advancedSaerching.htm). I can't reproduce the described problem. I see now your code I will analyse it...

Comment: Yes, from navGrid it's working ok.  I also tried it from the navGrid and it's working ok from navGrid.  Thanks for looking into it.  It would help me a lot  know how to tweak it so it will also work from the searchGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the problem can't be reproduced on the standard usage of (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/advancedSaerching.htm)).

I can't follow all parts of the code fragment which you posted, but the reason of the described problem seems the the following: You use the option `sFilter: "afilters"` which means that you want rename default `filters` property used by jqGrid in `postData` for saving the filter to `afilters`. OK. Then you included the line `delete postData.afilters;` inside of `onSearch`. **It destroys the filter.** So there are no more information about previous filter. Because of that jqGrid will be not able to display the previous filter at the next opening of the searching dialog. **To fix the problem you should remove the line `delete postData.afilters;`** for your code.

Comment: You are right.  I need to remove the aFilter couse my server don't except so many filters and I'm building internally a toolbarfilter, advanced and post grouping filters all together.  What I forgot to do is to return it back at gridComplete callback.